# Conversion of datetime64 to datetime.date object

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a dataframe with one column as a series of calender dates using

```
start = datetime.date(2008, 8, 01)
end = datetime.date(2009, 1, 19)
range = pd.date_range(start, end, freq = 'D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.Series(range)})
```

By this I get the type of date column as datetime64[ns] although I used the datetime.date to create the dates. I have looked through a few questions but didn't really find them helpful.

How can I convert the type of the date column of this dataframe to a date object?

Comment: Pandas uses `datetime[ns]` for all dates outside of period indexes, and it's very likely that's what you want to be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_range` indeed returns datetime64, regardless of how you specify start and end (eg these can also be strings).
If you want to convert `datetime64` values to `datetime.date` objects, you can use the `.date` accessor of DatetimeIndex (`date_range` returns such an index):

```
In [22]: s = pd.Series(range.date)

In [23]: s
Out[23]:
0     2008-08-01
1     2008-08-02
2     2008-08-03
3     2008-08-04
4     2008-08-05
...
167    2009-01-15
168    2009-01-16
169    2009-01-17
170    2009-01-18
171    2009-01-19
Length: 172, dtype: object

In [24]: s[0]
Out[24]: datetime.date(2008, 8, 1)
```

See here for docs on these datetime components: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components. To convert it to `datetime.datetime` objects, you can use `range.to_pydatetime()`.

But as U2EF1, dependent on the application, it's quite possible you want such `datetime64` values, as operations with it will be much more performant.